# Odoo 10: Cant parse date field using Element tree in python

Tags: python, xml, model, odoo, elementtree

I defined a field in models.py :

```
activation_date = fields.Char(string='Activation Date')
```

In this field I want to add a value which is coming from a response xml of SOAP api call.I am using Element tree to parse the  response xml :

```
response=requests.post(self.url,cert=self.cert,data=body,headers=self.headers) 
 element = ElementTree.fromstring(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
 body_el = element.find('{schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope}Body')
 getSubscriptionsResponse = body_el.find('{http://www.example.com}getSubscriptionsResponse')         
 activation_date_from_xml=getSubscriptionsResponse.find('{http://www.example.com}activationDate')
```

I want to add this **activation_date_from_xml** to my **activation_date** using create method  :

```
record.sudo().create({
                       "activation_date": activation_date_from_xml.text,

                                       })
              http.request.env.cr.commit()
```

But i get an error :

```
in parseXml
    "activation_date": activation_date_from_xml.text,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

**Info** :The value of the the activationDate element in the response xml is :

```
2017-10-27T00:00:00+00:00
```

How to get this value and save it in my field using Element tree??

Comment: It will be helpful if you share the value that you are getting as response in `response.content`

Comment: response.content : <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <wstxns1:getSubscriptionsResponse xmlns:wstxns1="http://www.example.com">
         
          <wstxns1:activationDate>2017-10-27T00:00:00+00:00</wstxns1:activationDate>
     
        </wstxns1:getSubscriptionsResponse>
                  
    </soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>

Comment: You need to be very careful with the namespace names. If it says `schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` in the XML, it does not work if you use `schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope` (note the missing slash) in the Python code.